# How is this smodin.io AI-generated Chinese passage?

Tags: grammar, writing-critique, mistakes

I generated this story using [smodin.io](https://smodin.io/zh-cn/%E4%BD%9C%E5%AE%B6) (my input was the title):

> #### 我被友好的外星人绑架了。
>
> 有史以来最引人入胜的电影之一是 H.G. 威尔斯的《世界大战》。这部电影描绘了外星人入侵地球，人类使用大规模杀伤性武器反击外星人。在整部电影中，人类主角都在努力理解他受到外星人攻击的事实。他最终屈服于外星人的精神控制并被他们绑架。这是电影中一个著名的场景，人类主角站在建筑物的顶部，外星飞船在他上方盘旋。这一幕虽然对读过书的人有很多共鸣，但其实是虚构的；从来没有人被友好的外星人绑架过。话虽如此，关于外星人绑架有几种理论；以下是对人类被外星人带走时发生的情况的一些可能解释。
>
> 首先，需要指出的是，目前还没有任何经证实的人类被敌对外星人绑架的案例。然而，已经有几起经过核实的人被仁慈的外星人绑架的案例。最著名的外星人绑架案是贝蒂·希尔，她曾两次被外星人劫持。每次她被绑架都与前一次不同；在她被绑架期间，她甚至还有两个背景不同的孩子。人们相信，外星人绑架是一种神经编程技术，被仁慈的外星人用来教给我们教训。换句话说，人们认为外星人绑架是一种心灵感应催眠，允许仁慈的外星人在精神上改变人的大脑，然后将其从身体中移除。
>
> 还值得一提的是，外星人绑架有着丰富的文学史——来自科学从《星际迷航》这样的小说到像安妮贝尔这样的超自然浪漫史，外星人在整个历史中都侵入了我们的梦想并偷走了我们。许多人相信这种现象，许多人在已发表和未发表的作品中写下了他们的经历。然而，这些说法中的大多数都被认为是恶作剧或幻觉，尤其是在没有任何科学证据支持的情况下。尽管许多人相信外星人绑架，但它并没有像视频游戏或互联网模因等其他现象那样获得主流媒体的关注。
>
> 现在我们已经讨论了人类被绑架时发生的一些可能的解释。外星人，让我们讨论某些被绑架者如何解释他们的经历。首先 - 重要的是要指出并不是每个遇到过的人都相信外星人假说（外星人存在的想法）。例如，演员 Ivan 'The Alien' Novitskiy 表示他不相信 UFO 绑架事件，而喜剧演员 Pete Shields 也不相信他自己与友好外星人的经历——相反，他认为这是一种幻觉。这导致许多研究人员认为，外星人绑架是仁慈的外星人使用的一种精神控制形式，通过催眠给我们上课。换句话说——人们认为他们被友好的外星人绑架，然后下意识地重新编程以相信它发生了。——关于外星人绑架是如何发生的以及在这些事件中发生了什么，有几种假设。最常见的是人们被仁慈的外星人绑架，他们使用心灵感应催眠将积极的想法植入他们的脑海。例如-人们可能会被绑架并被告知他们是神或精神领袖，他们是为地球上的特殊目的而被选中的。或者——人们可能会被告知他们是正在对他们进行的实验的一部分，并将成为被称为“小灰人”的一种新的性欲亢进种族的一部分。无论哪种方式 - 在人们被绑架后，与其他没有经历过这些经历的人相比，他们往往对发生在他们身上的事情有截然不同的看法。
>
> 从第三类亲密接触等电影到绑架等书籍- 无论你在哪里被外星人扣为人质，人们都喜欢思考外星人绑架的奥秘！正如我们从 Betty Hill 和 Ivan Novitskiy 等著名案例中看到的那样——人类确实会堕落

My impression is that it's "locally grammatical" (I didn't find any obvious grammar errors) but sometimes it's illogical, like how 贝蒂·希尔 was abducted by aliens twice, but 每次她被绑架都与前一次不同 ("every time she was abducted was different to the previous time").  It also seems abruptly cut off at the end.

I'm curious if I can use this to generate example sentences and snippets for actual study.

**Question**: How is this smodin.io AI-generated Chinese passage?

Answer (score 7):

The grammar / wording gives me the feeling that it's an English passage translated into Chinese, and the translator did a poor job. Some parts are not even locally grammatical. Considerable modification is needed:

1. Non-idiomatic expression:

这是(Here is)电影中一个著名的场景(famous scene)，人类主角站在建筑物的顶部(top of a building)，外星飞船在他上方盘旋。 → 电影中有**这样**一个**名场面**：人类主角站在**楼顶**，外星飞船在上空盘旋。

2. Wordy sentence:

人们可能会被告知他们是正在对他们进行的实验的一部分，并将成为被称为“小灰人”的一种新的性欲亢进种族的一部分。→ 人类可能会被当成**实验室里的小白鼠**，被改造成性欲亢进的“小灰人”。

她曾两次被外星人劫持。每次她被绑架都与前一次不同。 → 她曾两次被外星人**以不同方式**劫持。

3. Incorrect parsing:

来自科学从《星际迷航》这样的小说("from science fictions such as Star Trek", mistranslated as "from science / fictions such as Star Trek")到像安妮贝尔这样的超自然浪漫史 → 从《星际迷航》这样的**科幻小说**到像安妮贝尔这样的超自然浪漫史

4. Unclear reference:

这一幕虽然对读过书(Book? My guess is the novel the film is adapted from. In Chinese it's not 书 but 原著。) 的人有很多共鸣，但其实是虚构的。→ 这一幕虽然让读过**原著**的观众**感同身受**，但其实是虚构的。

These errors make the whole passage "alien" to a native speaker. I won't recommend anyone to use it for actual study.