# AIs that can construct Chinese conversations

Tags: resources, reading, listening, technology

Does anybody know of any free/affordable AIs (a la Chat GPT) that are pretty good at constructing simple Chinese dialogues?

Comment: Chat GPT itself is good

Comment: See also [How is this smodin.io AI-generated Chinese passage?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/53077/8099) for a critique of an AI-written passage.

Comment: There's now a [AI chat bot](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese/54389#54389) section for the resources page.  There's quite a lot of Chinese-speaking bots nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned the two best ai's I am aware of, however please take care:

there is not currently an ai capable of genuinely constructing a conversation, as they cannot properly understand context (refer to winograd schema if interested in the nerdy side).

if not interested in the nerdy side, know that it is the same basic issue that causes you to ask your phone "please make a note of that" and now you have a note that says "that."

of course, ai like chat gpt or characters ai are more sophisticated than your average siri or alexia.  they are still using a combination of machine translation, text prediction, and scanning of existing texts online etc.

this can make them dangerously innacurate but very believable when used as a learning resource.

that said as a warning, they aren't useless.  just keep in mind the limitations of such ai in general and try to keep the subject matter to what you already know-- that way you will be able to recognize any errors.  it is a common logical fallacy to expect to catch an error in new information. As long as we are aware to avoid new info with unreliable sources everything is all good :)

Answer (score 0):

[Character.AI](https://beta.character.ai) is heading in that direction, but is currently in beta.  It has a range of Chinese-speaking bots, such as [Chinese Teacher](https://beta.character.ai/chat?char=s6ZpWy629kcqPezBFyrBzdyKE_4uALQQTK1h771r0o4), [Hyperglot](https://beta.character.ai/chat?char=2T3Xhqf5B_b9Wrn8Bg0FeCYR7BPx2LtJQJJCIB4Qe18), and [Wiluka](https://beta.character.ai/chat?char=8gWu8GanuF2PA3U_T5PyEm7nWcAHXeE4mUifs94bh6I).